# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{\ln(2n+1)}{2n+1} = \frac{\pi}{4}(\gamma - \ln \pi) + \pi \ln \Gamma(\frac{3}{4})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{\ln(2n+1)}{2n+1} =\frac\pi4(\gamma-\ln\pi)+\pi\ln\Gamma(3/4)$$
This sum was obtained by Malmsten in 1842. I researched this series and found no proof. I also saw that this series is the derivative of Dirichlet's beta function at point 1. I tried to turn the series into an integral from 0 to 1, but I did not succeed.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Fourier_series_expansion

Comment: Why do you reject the proof you have given: it is the derivative of Dirichlet's beta function evaluated at $1$?

Comment: I would like a direct proof.

Comment: With Mathematica I have:$\frac{1}{4} \left(-\gamma _1\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)+\gamma _1\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)-\pi  \ln (4)\right)$, where: $\gamma _1\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)$ and $\gamma _1\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$ is generalized Stieltjes constant.